# Deviseでエラー「undefined method `errors' for #<User::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x007fd10be58b00>」

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

users/edit　のリンクを押すと下のようなエラーが出ます。

> NoMethodError in Users::Registrations#edit

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'user/show'

  devise_for :users, controllers: { :omniauth_callbacks => "omniauth_callbacks", :registrations => "users/registrations" }

  root 'home#index'
  get 'home/show'

  #User MyPage
  resources :users
```

このエラーはなぜ起きるのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: 現象を再現するための手順またはコードを記載してください

Comment: githubにエラーのでるアプリケーションを用意しました。サインアップ後ログインをし、マイページを押すと該当のエラーがおきます。ご確認お願いします。https://github.com/tib777/sample